# C# out struct parameter

Tags: c#, struct

I have this code in C# but I have a problem whit this code:

```
struct myStruct
{
  public string sOne;
  public string sTwo;
}

public static int ChangeStruct(out myStruct[] arrmyStruct)
{
  arrmyStruct= new myStruct[256];
  arrSNChildrenStruct[0].sOne= "";
  arrSNChildrenStruct[0].sTwo= "";

  return 0;
}
```

But when I build, I have this error:
Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'out ........ is less accessible than method .....

What's wrong?
Thanks

Comment: make myStruct public, it is internal by default

Comment: When don't specify any access specefier it takes Internal as default. Hence to make it public write it like.. **public struct myStruct**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make a `public struct myStruct` instead of internal struct. Or make ChangeStruct() `private` if you only use it locally.

Answer (score 5):

This has nothing to do with it being an `out` parameter, or an array. You'd get the same error with:

```
public static void ChangeStruct(myStruct foo)
```

Your *method* is public, but your *struct* is `internal` (the default accessibility for any top-level type) or `private` if it's a nested type. That means that any caller external to your assembly should have access to the method... but can't possibly understand the method signature. C# doesn't allow you to declare methods which refer to types which can't be seen by all possible callers.

Options:

- Make the method `internal` or `private`
- Make the struct public

Other notes:

- Your naming is very unconventional. Name your types according to their meaning, and make it PascalCased. Drop the "arr" prefix from your variable names.
- Public fields are usually a bad idea, as are mutable structs.